# Question on complex numbers - to find if the functi0n is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I have two queries here,

1. Can $g(z) = f(\bar{z})$  , and $h(z)$  = $\overline{f(z)}$ be analytic in D?
2. If $g(z)$ and $h(z)$ both are analytic in D then what can be said about $f(z)$ throughout $D$.

My approach was:

I tried using the equations $$\frac{df}{d\bar{z}} = \frac{d\overline{f}} {d\bar{z}} =0 ---- (1) $$

$\frac{dg(z)}{d\bar{z}} \neq 0 $ as $g(z)$ depends on $\bar{z}$ but $\overline{f(z)}$ can be analytic.

Hence $g(\bar{z}) $ cannot be analytic but $\overline{f(z)} $ is analyic if it is a constant.

But this logic contradicts statement of my query.

Please help

Thanks.

Comment: If z has imaginary part 0 then $z = u(x,y)$. Then its a real function.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that $h(z)$ can be analytic if it's constant but $g(z)$ can't. If $f(z)$ is constant then so are $h(z)$ and $g(z)$, and all three of them are everywhere analytic.

Comment: $g(z)$ can be analytic, take for eaxmple $f(z)=\bar z$. Then $g(z)=f(\bar z) = z$, so $g(z)=z$ and it is analytic.

Comment: How should I prove it but .Any clue

Answer (score 1):

Take $g(z)$ to be any analytic function and define $f(z)=g(\bar{z})\ \ $ 
($f$ is anti-holomorphic). Then $g(z)=f(\bar{z})$ is analytic by definition. Now the function
$h(z)=\overline{f(z)} = \overline{g(\bar{z})} = \overline{g}(z)$
is again analytic. For the definition of the last function you may e.g. think of
$ g(z) = \sum_k a_k z^k$ for which $\bar{g}(z)=\sum_k \bar{a_k} z^k$.

If $g$ is holomorphic in $D$ then $h$ is holomorphic in $\overline{D}$ (which equals $D$ if $D$ means the unit disk). So $f$ is anti-holomorphic in the union of $D$ and $\overline{D}$. (and $h$ and $g$ are analytic there).